# Napili Feature Topic Images

Tags: css, lightning-community, napili, topics

Has anyone found a way to resize the featured topic images on the Napili templates. They just take up too much screen real estate. They also seem to have a grey filter on them so when I use white background images they come out grey and horrible looking.

I have tried using CSS but to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the community builder, under Branding, Edit CSS

[image]

You can reference the element>class and modify the size:

```
li.topicItem.forceTopicFeaturedTopicItem{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
}
```

[image]

[image]